# Parse iOS SDK: How to set user "online" status?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Scenario = I have an app that allows users to log in and view other users who are also "online". In order to set each user's online status I believe that I should set the code...

```
[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isOnline"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

at certain times in the application when the user uses the app. Probably the appDelegate but I'm not sure.

(if this is not correct then please correct me)

Question = Where should this code be set inside the application so that it always keeps track of when a user is "online" and when they are "offline"?

(please include method names)

Comment: There's no reliable way to do this, as you can't guarantee you'll be able to set it to false when they close the app.  If you're changing something on the user (like incrementing a run counter) you can infer from the updatedAt field who was online recently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most reliable way to handle this is to create a column named `lastActive` of type Date, then create a Cloud Code function to update this with the server time (so clock differences isn't an issue).

Then to get "online" users just have another Cloud Function that does a query where `lastActive` is greater than now - some time window like 2 minutes.

```
var moment = require("moment");

Parse.Cloud.define("registerActivity", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    user.set("lastActive", new Date());
    user.save().then(function (user) {
        response.success();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.error(error);
    });
});

Parse.Cloud.define("getOnlineUsers", function(request, response) {
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    var activeSince = moment().subtract("minutes", 2).toDate();
    userQuery.greaterThan("lastActive", activeSince);
    userQuery.find().then(function (users) {
        response.success(users);
    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Your client will want to call the `registerActivity` Cloud Function every 1.5 minutes to allow some overlap so users don't appear to go offline if their internet is a bit slow.

Of course you can adjust the time windows to suit your needs. You could also add the ability to filter which users are returned (e.g. online friends only).

Comment: **1**) When do I call these inside Xcode to get this to work? Or will it work just by placing this inside the main.js file? **2**) How do I update my user's label inside my app to display "Online" from these cloud code functions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do I call "registerActivity" in the AppDelegate or something? Do I call "getOnlineUsers" every time I have an "onlineLabel" that needs to be populated with an "Online" or "Offline" text?

Comment: As stated, your app will need to call "registerActivity" every 1.5 minutes to let the server know you are still online. Anytime you want to know what users are online you will need to call "getOnlineUsers". Please re-read the last 2 paragraphs of my answer.

Comment: I apologize. I was not very specific in my question. I meant in what method do I call a registerActivity? applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: You would want to call it there, as well as setting up some kind of timer to continue to call it. Effectively your code has to "nag" the server with "still online" at regular intervals.

Comment: Is nagging the server at regular intervals be detrimental to my "requests per sec" count?

Comment: I recently discovered that the 30/sec is actually calculated by the minute, so you get 3600/min. Depending on how accurate you want the "Online" status to be, you're talking about 1 hit per active user every 1-5 minutes. Work out an interval that works well for you. Just make sure the server interval allows for an extra 30 seconds or so 'grace period'.